# Visual Studio 2013 C++ Build Fail

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Previous of this odd occurrence, I could compile all of my c++ projects in Visual Studio 2013. However, the other day all of my projects that were working before, now are unable to be run. A prompt comes up saying that *"The system file cannot be specified"*. I have this example project:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

float get_Farenhiet_Temperature(float x) {
    x = x * 9;
    x = x / 5;
    x = x + 32;
    return x;
}

float get_Celcius_Temperature(float y) {
    y = y - 32;
    y = y * 5;
    y = y / 9;
    return y;
}

int main() {
    float farenheit;
    float celcius;
    float extra;
    // this extra will be used to let the original values be able to stay themselves
    cout << "For Celcius to Farenheit conversion, please enter you temperature of Celcius: " << endl;
    cin >> celcius;

    celcius = extra;
    get_Farenhiet_Temperature(extra);
    extra = farenheit;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed;
    cout << "Your conversion from: " << celcius << "degress Celcius, to now: " << "degrees Farenheit!" << endl;
    cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be great thank you.

Comment: This does not seem to be the real code, because `#include <iostream>` is missing and the Visual C++ 2013 on my machine does not implicitly include `<iostream>` with `<iomanip>`. You have also not told us your compiler settings.

Comment: I am new to visual studio and c++ programming, so my mistake. But how is this not the real code? Also, I cannot find where to view, or even how to, the compiler settings. I cannot find the property page.

Comment: It does not seem to be real because when I copy and paste it into my editor and try to compile it with Visual C++, it complains about `cout` et al, due to a missing `#include <iostream>`. As for the compiler settings, if you cannot find the property page in Visual Studio, then I'd say this is a much more urgent problem, isn't it? You *must* be able to access the compiler settings somehow.

Comment: However, I must admit that `"The system file cannot be specified"` sounds like a very, very unsual compiler message. My first intuition would be a broken installation and that you might need to reinstall everything.

Comment: I figured out the problem. All along, I was getting the error "error C4700". I googled this, and finally realized that some variables needed to be set to zero before use. My new includes just setting "Fahrenheit" and "extra" to 0. Thanks for your help!